# SOQL query for events with who.createddate = this year

Tags: soql, event

I'm trying to query for events where the Name (`whoID`) lead or contact was created within a certain time frame. This is what I have but it's giving me an error using the field `who.createddate`.

```
select meeting_outcome__c, what.name 
from event 
where who.createddate = 'this year' 
  and meeting_outcome__c = 'Sales Accepted Lead'
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as though you're looking for a condition where the `(WhoId = (Lead.Id || Contact.Id) AND (Lead.createdDate or Contact.createdDate) >= (Today().addDays(-365)))`.

There is no `What.name` field and the WhoId's `createdDeate` can't be referenced using the WhoId, instead only by using the Object it comes from. So, you'd otherwise have to break this up into separate queries if something like the above won't work for you.

BTW, I likely haven't properly referenced the Today() - 1 year by using apex code. I'm confident there's an easier way to do it, but don't have the time to look it up. It should be in the [SOQL reference Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/index.htm).

Comment: You can actually use the NEXT_N_DAYS:n literal  for things like that: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm

Comment: I would think you would use LAST_N_DAYS:365. Also, it's in beta but polymorphic queries would really help here.

Comment: I knew someone would pop in with the easy way to do it. Thanks guys. :)